# API calls not returning response with MySQL data streams

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, streaming, node-streams

I have the following code:

```
await axiosAPICall(dummyData); // works

const sqlQuery = `SELECT column1, column2 FROM table`;
const queryStream = mySqlConnectionInstance.query(sqlQuery, []);

queryStream
    .on('error', function (err) {
        // Handle error, an 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
    })
    .on('result', async (actualData) => {
        // axios api call, the api callback goes to callstack with any of the following errors:
       // 1. read ECONNRESET 
       // 2. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

      await axiosAPICall(actualData); // breaks

    })
    .on('end', function () {
        // all rows have been received
    });
```

As you can see I'm getting all the rows from a table in a [MySQL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) database stream. When the data comes from the database stream, I'm passing that data to the [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) API call.

The API call works perfectly fine when called outside of the stream logic but when I call the API inside the streaming logic, it breaks all the time.

I am hitting API calls as fast as each `on('result')` gets called (the async/await does NOT slow down the request rate, i.e. I end up with multiple requests in parallel.

Does anyone know why is API calls not working inside the streaming logic section?

If the question needs any clarifications please comment.

Comment: is the format of `dummyData` identical to the content of `actualData`

Comment: Yes, same format @JaromandaX

Comment: `axiosAPICall` suggests you are making a request of some API? perhaps you're hitting it too quick - since you will be hitting it as fast as each on result gets called (the async/await will NOT slow down the request rate, i.e. you WILL end up with multiple requests in parallel)

Comment: @JaromandaX correct, that's exactly the problem, that is the actual problem why I posted the question, what is the solution for that?

Comment: It's odd you never mentioned that the issue is with making too many requests too quickly ... that would've made the solution obvious from the beginning :p

Answer (score 1):

Based on a comment that suggests the error is due to making "too many requests" at once - this is a simple and naive way to wait for the previous request before making the next

```
const sqlQuery = `SELECT column1, column2 FROM table`;
const queryStream = mySqlConnectionInstance.query(sqlQuery, []);

const wait = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

let previous = Promise.resolve();
queryStream
    .on('error', function (err) {
        // Handle error, an 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
    })
    .on('result', async (actualData) => {
      // wait until previous request has completed
      await previous;

      // optional, add a delay, 
      // 100ms for this example - 
      // for example if there is a limit of 10 requests per second
      // adjust (or remove) as required

      await wait(100); 

      // set "previous" for next request
      previous = axiosAPICall(actualData);
    })
    .on('end', function () {
        // if you `await previous` here, 
        // you can truly wait until all rows are processed
        // all rows have been received
    });
```